# unable to creating maven project in spring tool suit

Tags: spring, maven, suite

[image]

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for what makes a good question. You need to post your code as well as the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do to run a Maven Project?

First you should download all the dependencies for Maven.

1) Right click -> maven -> download dependency
2) Run -> maven build 
3) Run ->  maven test